# Student roll number generation and store in database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a asp.net webforms application, where student can fill up a form and submit. The student information then gets saved to a database. There is a system to auto generate their academic roll number. To accomplish this task i created a separate table which has only one column named "LastRollNumber". The table also have an ID column. The table always have one row only. So if a student admit himself/herself then after submitting the form the application will check the table for last roll number and will add 1 and update the table. I used the following SQL to do that:

```
"UPDATE [dbo].[AcademicRollData] SET [LastRollNumber] = [LastRollNumber] +1 OUTPUT inserted.LastRollNumber WHERE [ID]=1;"
```

Many students are accessing the application. The application is working fine but some rollnumber is getting missed. There is no duplicate in roll number but sometimes it is missing. What i am doing wrong? What is the best way to accomplish this task? Please help me with your valuable answer to resolve the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Most RDBMS (you haven't tagged yours) support some sort of auto-incrementing sequence, why not just use that?

Comment: I can not use Identity auto incrementing functionality as the roll number sequence gets different each year. For year 2022 the roll will start with 20220001 and it will be changed each year. Also there are 3 different academic group and each group have different sequence.

Comment: Sounds like you need a computed column or a view that returns the required column.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried scope_identity()

```
dim cmd as sqlcommand=new sqlcommand("insert into table () values();SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)",connection)
dim LastRollNumber as integer=cmd.ExecuteScalar

cmd=new sqlcommand("UPDATE [dbo].[AcademicRollData] SET [LastRollNumber] = " & LastRollNumber +1 & " WHERE [ID]=" & LastRollNumber",connection)
```

Comment: scope_identity() is product specific, the OP has only tagged ISO SQL....

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you don't need to create a separate table for generating roll number. Recommended way is to use max()+1. Additionally, you can make column unique and not null to avoid duplicate and null values. Also lock the table or use transactional scope.

Example query to insert

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[AcademicRollData]
( rollNumber, column1, otherColumn )
VALUES 
((SELECT MAX( rollNumber )+1 FROM [dbo].[AcademicRollData] acaRollData), 
'value1', 'value')
```

In this case, you don't need to run an additional update query.

Please let me know if understood your purpose.

Comment: This approach is not recommended. It suffers from concurrency issues - two people can end up with the same number

Comment: If we use transactional scope and make column unique, then we can prevent such duplications. However, scope_identity() will not give uniform number like 1,2, 3, 4,... because sometimes, if your server is restarted or rows deleted then value will be different.

Comment: I can make the column Unique. Then how to handle the errors for duplicate values. If there is an error then try to submit the same SQL in the catch statement? Also can you please provide an example using the transactional scope? That is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use identity column that auto-increments with a seed that you specify at 1. You can also use a sequence in Oracle and SQL Server.

Comment: I can not use Identity auto incrementing functionality as the roll number sequence gets different each year. For year 2022 the roll will start with 20220001 and it will be changed each year. Also there are 3 different academic group and each group have different sequence.

Comment: You can schedule a job at the beginning of the new year to reseed the table id `DBCC CHECKIDENT (
'TableName', 
RESEED, 
year(getdate()) * 10000 +1
)`